# Are there opensource hierarchical database management systems

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I was looking for a hierarchical database management system and the only one i came across was IBM's ims.Are there opensource systems that one can use?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since XML databases are hierarchical, you could look at those. I recently used [BaseX](http://basex.org/) and liked it a lot.

Comment: Assuming your entire database can be represented as a single huge XML document!

Comment: Of course you can split your data over several documents...

Comment: @objectiveME: this should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: i made the change (from comment to answer).

Comment: Here is a list of XML databases from wikipeida... I like eXist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#Native_XML_databases

Answer (score 4):

Any LDAP implementation is going to be hierarchical, or at least exposed as such, even if the backend's something else.

- [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/).
- [Apache Directory](http://directory.apache.org/)

(There's likely others, and even Apple's Open Directory, but I don't know if that one has a dedicated project page)

Answer (score 2):

I found mumps and its GPL licensed.***Mumps (also referred to as M) is a general purpose programming language that supports a unique, hierarchical (or multidimensional) database facility ***   http://cs.uni.edu/~okane/mumps.html

**Update**

***Important Links.***

-http://gradvs1.mgateway.com/main/

-http://www.intersystems.com/

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a document-oriented database that stores [binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/). It's an open-source database with actual [corporate backing](http://10gen.com/).

In terms of hierarchical, it stores "documents" instead of "records" in "collections" instead of "tables". Using JSON, it's easy to create objects that represent hierarchical data. It also supports indexing and querying "into" these documents.

If you're thinking of XML databases, JSON should be competitive.

Comment: XML and JSON are *nothing* like IMS...

Answer (score 1):

It is not open source, but Microsoft SQL 2008 Management Studio Express is free and allows XML datatypes starting with SQL Server 2005.  If you are not familiar with using the XML datatype to store heirarchies,  I am currently reading a book by Michael Coles called Pro SQL Server 2008 XML which introduces using XML in SQL.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b